# How old is the current society on Jackson's Whole?

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

I've read somewhere that as few as 100 years have passed since Jackson's Whole was just a "pirates' nest", but that doesn't seem to fit the rather extensive "civilization" they have.

Are there any canonical sources I'm missing, or can we assume just... any age?

**EDIT**: Obviously they are younger than Beta Colony, and I would guess that they were not yet a "civilization" when Barrayar was lost, but with 5 wormholes (and thus 5 implied "neighbors") they must have had some defenses early on.

Comment: I'd love to see some kind of wacky crossover featuring the Jacksonians and Weber's gangsters-turned-"honest", who named their capital city Maytag.  You can just see the (wink wink nudge nudge) in all their tourist brochures...

Comment: Where did you read this ? Ryoval was already 100 years old on Miles first visit there.